# Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda failed to launch

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda and upon launching Jupyter Notebook, I encountered an error:

```
Traceback (most     recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\MY PC\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in
from    notebook.notebookapp import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'
```

I have tried installing: `conda install pyzmq=22`

Comment: It always makes me cringe when I see spaces in file paths, such as yours here `C:\Users\My PC\...` This can wreck scripts. Anyway ... take a closer look at that script?